# CGContext Ref as UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext

Trying to create a UIimage from a Draw Context.
Not seeing anything. Am i missing something, or completely out my mind?

Code

```
- (UIImage *)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);


    // Do your stuff here
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is not a `-drawRect:` method on a view, because the return value is wrong. (`-[UIView drawRect:]` returns `void`, not a `UIImage*`.)

If it *is* on an NSView, that means you must be calling it directly, to get the return value. But that means that UIKit hasn't set up a graphics context, the way it normally does before it calls `-drawRect:` on the views in a window.

Therefore, you shouldn't assume that `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is valid. It's probably nil (have you checked?).

If you just want an image: use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` to create a context, then `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` to extract a `UIImage` (no need for the intermediary `CGImage`), then `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` to clean up.

If you're trying to capture an image of what your view drew: fix your `-drawRect:` to return void, and find some other way to get that UIImage out of the view -- either stash it in an ivar, or send it to some other object, or write it to a file, whatever you like.

Also (less importantly):

1. Don't `CGContextRelease(context)`. You didn't create, copy, or retain it, so you shouldn't release it.
2. No need for the last `CGContextAddLineToPoint()`. `CGContextFillPath` will implicitly close the path for you.